# "This script or class was runnable but could not be run"

Tags: groovy

I'm getting this error when running a groovy script (GroovyRuntimeException), and the top Google results are not clear/concise enough. What exactly does this error mean?

Comment: Some sort of source code or stack trace might prove helpful

Comment: Created an issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.5.4/groovy-1.5.4-sources.jar!/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java?format=ok), the script class does not have a main method and one of these is true:

- It has neither a parameterless constructor not one that takes a String array
- Or the constructor threw an exception

The stack trace should tell you which.

Comment: I think I didn't see a stack trace. I'll check it tomorrow, thanks for the pointer to the source.

Comment: There was no stack trace. The cause was a "compilation error" in the constructor. Followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985716/is-there-a-use-strict-for-groovy